# Prevent trigger focus event when clicking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to create my own dropdown component using React. It should open the options when the components get focus. And you should also be able to toggle the options when clicking on it.

I've created a [small example](http://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-davinci-r6g17) to reproduce the case.

The problem is when clicking the unfocused component both focus and click event are triggering and this will open and close the options. Once the element has focused the click events work like intended. Also using tab to get focus is working.

I don't have a good solution to prevent this behavior. `event.stopPropation()` is not working because these are 2 different events on the same element. My only solution is to have a "hasFocus"-state and set it with a short delay of 100ms and check for this inside the onClick function.

**Current behavior:** Dropdown element is unfocused. Click on the element will trigger the focus and click event which results in

```
ShowOptions: true
ShowOptions: false
```

So the options just flickering and will be hidden afterward

**Expected behavior:** Either focus or click event is triggered and options are shown.

Maybe you've some better solution to this problem.

Comment: I read your question a couple of times and still don't get it, can you elaborate the desired behavior better.

Comment: Don't you mean you want to open the dropdown `onHover` that `onFocus`?

Comment: Check this example, https://codesandbox.io/s/7u5x2 are you trying to make a dropdown similar to nav-3?

Comment: I've added the behaviour to the question

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: @DennisVash Thank your for this example. But this one is using hover. But I'm trying to work with click.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation` aren't helping because the events are not bubbling but spawned by browser on the element.

Answer (score 1):

As you said:

> Either focus or click event is triggered and options are shown.

So you need to use or `||` operator: `{(isOpen.isClicked || isOpen.isFocused) && <div>Options</div>}`

```js
const Dropdown = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({ isFocused: false, isClicked: false });

  const onFocus = () => {
    setIsOpen(prev => ({ ...prev, isFocused: true }));
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setIsOpen({ isFocused: false, isClicked: false });
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(prev => ({
      isClicked: !prev.isClicked,
      isFocused: false
    }));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        alignItems="stretch"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
      ...
      </Container>
      {(isOpen.isClicked || isOpen.isFocused) && <div>Options</div>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56656562]

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Unfortunately it's not covering all my cases. It's not possible to toggle the options (show/hide on click). And also on blur the options will not disappear. So hiding the options again is only possible when blur the element, focus it again and then blur again.

Comment: Misscopied, try again, the dropdown toggled `onClick`, showed `onFocus` and closed `onBlur`

Comment: Ok your solution showed me the right way. I've solved it a little bit different, because there is one last small thing left in your solution. When focusing the element by keyboard you have to click twice to hide the options. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by adding mousedown and mouseup events. Mousedown (and also touch events) are triggered before the focus event. So I can "bypass" the focus case when clicking on the element.

```
  const [showValues, setShowValues] = useState(false);
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);

  const onFocus = e => {
    if (!mouseDown) {
      setShowValues(true);
      console.log("focus");
    }
  };

  const onBlur = e => {
    setShowValues(false);
    console.log("blur");
  };

  const onClick = e => {
    setShowValues(!showValues);
    console.log("click");
  };

  const onMouseDown = () => {
    setMouseDown(true);
  };

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    setMouseDown(false);
  };
```